# Meteor Collection empty on server

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I got a collection named Admins and I use `Admins.findOne({userId: Meteor.userID})` to check if a user is an admin and it works fine if I do it when I use it in the meteor shell and when I call the method I have defined for it from the browser console, but when I do server-side permission checks with it the Admins collection appears to be empty (`Admins._collection._docs._map` is empty. I have checked.). I don't know why my method can't access it if I perform it on the server side, but works fine when I call it form the chrome dev tools. My methods are:

```
updateArticle: (id, obj) ->
    console.log Admins //appears to be empty
    console.log Meteor.userId()

    Meteor.call 'hasBasicPermissions', (err,res) ->
      console.log res // false
      if res
        Articles.update(id, obj)
      else
        Meteor.call('notAuthorisedError') // throws the error
isEditor: ->
  !!Editors.findOne {userId: Meteor.userId()} // return true when called in Meteor shell, but is false when used in the method, but only on the server side
isAdmin: ->
  !!Admins.findOne {userId: Meteor.userId()}
hasBasicPermissions: ->
  console.log(Meteor.userId())
  console.log(Admins)
  res = !!Admins.findOne({userId: "9fZmAnoJubaGDZH64"}) or !!Admins.findOne({userId: "9fZmAnoJubaGDZH64"})
  console.log res
  return res
notAuthorisedError : ->
  throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
```

Comment: Can you post the code how you instantiate your collection?

Comment: @MichelH before switching to roles i used Admins = new (Mongo.Collection)('admins')

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you’re defining your collection (the `@Admins = new Meteor.Collection('admins')` or similar line) in a place where the code is only executed on the client: within a file in the `client` folder, or inside a `Meteor.isClient` block. Try putting it in shared code, for example in a `lib` or `collections` folder.

Comment: I did solve the problem, by switching to the awesome roles package